# Dice with pictures for each number, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a game, where I have made a button, which prints out the number, in the dice. I want instead to print out the number, i want to print out a dice picture which i have made. How do I do that? The code i have on the "dice" for now is:

```
function rolldice(){
    var rollResultElem = document.getElementById("roll-result")
    var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
}
```

Comment: And where are your pictures located, what form sure the URL take? Where's your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

html image :

```
<img id="image1">
```

and then change image :

```
document.getElementById("image1").src = "path/dice/number"+rollResult+".jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Switch statement with different Pics, Select correct pic based on rollresult and then replace image src with the image selected.

```
var rollResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
switch(rollResult){
        case 1: {image = './one.jpeg'; break;}
        case 2: {image = './two.jpeg'; break;}
        case 3: {image = './three.jpeg'; break;}
        case 4: {image = './four.jpeg'; break;}
        case 5: {image = './five.jpeg'; break;}
        case 6: {image = './six.jpeg'; break;}
        default: break;
}
documet.getElementById('image').src = image;
```

Comment: wouldn't using an array be easier for this, instead of a switch?

Comment: @NickParsons Just an option, You can use `Array` or a simple js object. Switch is like more old school way as o/p seems very new to programming.

Comment: Ok, fair enough!